# словил баг когда делал слайдер

Tags: javascript, html, слайдер

не могу решить уже часов восемь. 
проблема в том, что при нескольких нажатиях на переключение кнопки "вперёд", все блоки с изображениями скрываются (у них у всех добавляется через цикл класс displaynone)
через инструменты разработчика хорошо видно, как это происходит.

---

- пытался делать функцию, которая отслеживает, есть у всех элементов
  класс displaynone и что-то делает с этим.
- шаманил с циклами и т.д

---

```js
const d = document;
/***************
       let
****************/
let body=d.querySelector("body")
let exampleBlockTexts=d.getElementsByClassName("imgDescript");
let exampleBlocks=d.getElementsByClassName("exampleBlock")
let prev=d.getElementsByClassName("prev")[0];
let next=d.getElementsByClassName("next")[0];

/**************
cut the text and add "..."
**************/
for(let exampleBlockText of exampleBlockTexts){
  
if(exampleBlockText.textContent.length>111){
  exampleBlockText.textContent=exampleBlockText.textContent.toString().slice(0,111);
  exampleBlockText.textContent+="..."
}
  
}
/***********
cut the exampleBlocks 
если блоков с изображениями >4 то, все остальные убираются, кроме первых 4-ех.
если их меньше, то просто убираю кнопки.
***********/
function cutBlocksAndButton(){
if(exampleBlocks.length>4){
  
  for(let i=4; i<exampleBlocks.length; i++){
     exampleBlocks[i].classList.add("displaynone");
   }
  
  for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
    exampleBlocks[i].classList.remove("displaynone");
    console.log("убираю дисплей нон у " + exampleBlocks[i].innerHTML)
  }
  // next.click() - на удивление не работает
   }
  else{
    prev && next.classList.add("displaynone")
  }
  console.log("обрезаю")
}
cutBlocksAndButton()

/****************
button functions 
****************/
var counter=0;
/*эта функция считает кол-во displaynone, и если они все имеют этот класс то вызывает функцию, которая сбрасывает всё это и выводит первые 4 блока*/
function checkDisplayNone(){
  let countDisplayNone=0;
  for(let i=0; i<exampleBlocks.length; i++){
    if(exampleBlocks[i].classList.contains("displaynone")){
      countDisplayNone++;
  }}
  if(countDisplayNone===exampleBlocks.length-4){
    cutBlocksAndButton()
}
}
/**************************************/
function nextSlide () {
  body.style.backgroundColor="lightgray" //просто для отладки
  counter+=4;
  counter = counter > exampleBlocks.length ? 0 : counter;

  //проверка сработает если длина элементов здесь делится нацело на 4, так как именно эту проблему решаю
   if((exampleBlocks.length % 4)===0){
    checkDisplayNone();
   }
  
  //2 цикла для отображения блоков с изображениями ( проблема может скрываться и тут)
  for(let i=0; i<counter; i++){
   exampleBlocks[i].classList.add("displaynone")
  }
  
  for(let i=counter; i<exampleBlocks.length; i++){
    exampleBlocks[i].classList.remove("displaynone")
  };
  
  return counter;
}
next.addEventListener("click", nextSlide)
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
 height:190px;
  
}
.clearfix::after{
 content: '';
 clear: both;
 height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 display:block;
}
.examplesList{
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  
  width:915px;

  padding:10px 0 0 0;
  
  box-shadow:
    0px -2px 0px #1558c4,
    0px 2px 0px #1558c4;
  
}
.exampleImgBlock{
  padding:0 10px 0px 10px;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  overflow:hidden;
  max-height:280px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.examplesList button{
 padding:20px 0;
 width:50%;
 border:none;
 outline:none;
 background:white;
 color:white;
 font-size:1.3em;
 cursor:pointer;
 display:block;
 background:rgba(21, 88, 196, 0.4);
 transition:all 0.09s ease-in;
}
.examplesList button:hover{
  background:#1558c4;
  background:rgba(21, 88, 196, 0.7);
  color:white;
  transition:all 0.09s ease-in;
}
.examplesList button.prev{
 float:left; 
  border-right:2px solid white;
}

.examplesList button.next{
  float:right;
    border-left:2px solid white;
}
.exampleBlock{
  max-width: 210px;
  max-height: 280px;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.examplesList a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
}
.examplesList .imgDescript{
  font-size:1.1em;
}




.displaynone{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="examplesList">
  <div class="exampleImgBlock clearfix">
    <div class="exampleBlock"><a href="#" class="exampleLink"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/NYCS-bull-trans-1.svg/1200px-NYCS-bull-trans-1.svg.png"  width="190px" height="125px" alt="" class="exampleImg"><span class="imgDescript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem facere soluta eveniet ab. Animi obcaecati, adipisci fugit, voluptatem similique necessitatibus eos molestias voluptatum nesciunt dolorum numquam dolorem labore tenetur tempore.</span></a></div>
    <div class="exampleBlock"><a href="#" class="exampleLink"><img src="https://номернедели.рф/gfx/200x200/2.png" alt="" class="exampleImg" width="190px" height="125px" ><span class="imgDescript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem facere soluta eveniet ab. Animi obcaecati, adipisci fugit, voluptatem similique necessitatibus eos molestias voluptatum nesciunt dolorum numquam dolorem labore tenetur tempore.</span></a></div>
    <div class="exampleBlock"><a href="#" class="exampleLink"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bb/TTC_-_Line_3_-_Scarborough_RT_line.svg/494px-TTC_-_Line_3_-_Scarborough_RT_line.svg.png" alt="" class="exampleImg"><span class="imgDescript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem facere soluta eveniet ab. Animi obcaecati, adipisci fugit, voluptatem similique necessitatibus eos molestias voluptatum nesciunt dolorum numquam dolorem labore tenetur tempore.</span></a></div>
    
     <div class="exampleBlock"><a href="#" class="exampleLink"><img src="https://vvelske.ru/media/posts/1/responsive/bus-number-4-velsk-md.jpg"  width="190px" height="125px" alt="" class="exampleImg"><span class="imgDescript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem facere soluta eveniet ab. Animi obcaecati, adipisci fugit, voluptatem similique necessitatibus eos molestias voluptatum nesciunt dolorum numquam dolorem labore tenetur tempore.</span></a></div>
    <div class="exampleBlock"><a href="#" class="exampleLink"><img src="https://5suiteslanzarote.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/5.png" alt="" class="exampleImg" width="190px" height="125px" ><span class="imgDescript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem facere soluta eveniet ab. Animi obcaecati, adipisci fugit, voluptatem similique necessitatibus eos molestias voluptatum nesciunt dolorum numquam dolorem labore tenetur tempore.</span></a></div>
    <div class="exampleBlock"><a href="#" class="exampleLink"><img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1001311/3411/i/450/depositphotos_34119663-stock-photo-3d-golden-number-collection-6.jpg" alt="" class="exampleImg"><span class="imgDescript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem facere soluta eveniet ab. Animi obcaecati, adipisci fugit, voluptatem similique necessitatibus eos molestias voluptatum nesciunt dolorum numquam dolorem labore tenetur tempore.</span></a></div>
     <div class="exampleBlock"><a href="#" class="exampleLink"><img src="https://st2.depositphotos.com/1598598/5822/i/450/depositphotos_58221667-stock-photo-red-balloon-with-ribbon.jpg"  width="190px" height="125px" alt="" class="exampleImg"><span class="imgDescript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem facere soluta eveniet ab. Animi obcaecati, adipisci fugit, voluptatem similique necessitatibus eos molestias voluptatum nesciunt dolorum numquam dolorem labore tenetur tempore.</span></a></div>
    <div class="exampleBlock"><a href="#" class="exampleLink"><img src="https://st3.depositphotos.com/1350793/14319/i/450/depositphotos_143199609-stock-photo-women-day-message-with-heart.jpg" alt="" class="exampleImg" width="190px" height="125px" ><span class="imgDescript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem facere soluta eveniet ab. Animi obcaecati, adipisci fugit, voluptatem similique necessitatibus eos molestias voluptatum nesciunt dolorum numquam dolorem labore tenetur tempore.</span></a></div>
    <div class="exampleBlock"><a href="#" class="exampleLink"><img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1498847/2684/i/450/depositphotos_26844461-stock-photo-number-9.jpg" alt="" class="exampleImg"><span class="imgDescript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem facere soluta eveniet ab. Animi obcaecati, adipisci fugit, voluptatem similique necessitatibus eos molestias voluptatum nesciunt dolorum numquam dolorem labore tenetur tempore.</span></a></div>
     <div class="exampleBlock"><a href="#" class="exampleLink"><img src="https://st2.depositphotos.com/2380107/5600/i/450/depositphotos_56008551-stock-photo-three-dimentional-red-number-collection.jpg"  width="190px" height="125px" alt="" class="exampleImg"><span class="imgDescript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem facere soluta eveniet ab. Animi obcaecati, adipisci fugit, voluptatem similique necessitatibus eos molestias voluptatum nesciunt dolorum numquam dolorem labore tenetur tempore.</span></a></div>
    <div class="exampleBlock"><a href="#" class="exampleLink"><img src="https://st2.depositphotos.com/2809911/9325/i/450/depositphotos_93257080-stock-photo-3d-number-11-gold.jpg" alt="" class="exampleImg" width="190px" height="125px" ><span class="imgDescript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem facere soluta eveniet ab. Animi obcaecati, adipisci fugit, voluptatem similique necessitatibus eos molestias voluptatum nesciunt dolorum numquam dolorem labore tenetur tempore.</span></a></div>
    <div class="exampleBlock"><a href="#" class="exampleLink"><img src="https://st4.depositphotos.com/21486874/24145/i/450/depositphotos_241453094-stock-photo-number-happy-birthday-colorful-paper.jpg" alt="" class="exampleImg"><span class="imgDescript">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem facere soluta eveniet ab. Animi obcaecati, adipisci fugit, voluptatem similique necessitatibus eos molestias voluptatum nesciunt dolorum numquam dolorem labore tenetur tempore.</span></a></div>
   </div>
  <button class="prev" title="назад" type="button"> < </button>
    <button class="next" title="вперёд" type="button"> > </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне не чем сейчас проверить, но мне кажется, что проблема в том, что Вы путаетесь в том, что массив и счётчик начинаются с нуля, а заканчиваются на отметке длина минус один. И с самой длиной, которая начинается не с нуля, а с единицы.

Comment: В общем, попробуйте вот тут поставить знак равно, чтобы было так: `counter = counter >= exampleBlocks.length ? 0 : counter;`

Answer (score 0):

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/311477/roman-bush дал правильный ответ.
нужно было исправить, добавив знак "="

counter = counter >= exampleBlocks.length ? 0 : counter;